# Avoiding hard-wired field access

Tags: java, dynamic, field

I want to refactor my code, because it contains redundant class-declarations.

I have a class of type ContainerClass1. Let’s assume the class-type contains only an field for an int-variable named „content“.

Another class of type ContainerFiller1 contains a method, that takes an instance of ContainerClass1 as a parameter and sets the field to a certain value. ContainerFiller1 looks like this:

```
 public class ContainerFiller1 {

    public void fill( ContainerClass object_A ) {
        object_A.content = 99;      
    }

 }
```

So I‘m using the dot-notation to declare, where to find the field (in object_A in this case).

I have eight other objects as instances of class `ContainerClass (ContainerClass  object_B, ContainerClass object_C, ContainerClass object_D, etc.)`.

And here‘s my problem: `object_A.content = 99` is hard-wired, so within the dot-notation I can not take the object-name as a variable to adjust my path to the field. As a workaround I have declared nine separate `ContainerFiller-Classes ( ContainerFiller1, …,  ContainerFiller9)` with each one having a different field-setter. As an example `ContainerFiller2` contains a hard-wired setter `object_B.content = 99` .

I want to get rid of my redundant classes and make a universal class of type `ContainerFiller` out of them. Is there a way to change the field-setter-notion in a way, I can reference the object-name in the parameter-list of `fill(ContainerClass anyObject)` and adjust the field-setter dynamically? Suggestions for alternatives for the dot-notation would be welcome as well.

Thanks in advance

Threx

Comment: How is `object_A` hardwired? It's a parameter passed to the method `fill`. So whichever instance passed to `fill` becomes `object_A` inside that method.

Comment: @jingx Even with an existing object_A around in the surrounding scope?

Comment: What surrounding scope? There are no global variables in Java, and in your `ContainerFiller1` class there isn't an instance variable named `object_A`. Even if there was, the parameter name still would take precedence.

Comment: @Threx, please provide other examples. How varied are the "contents" and how varied are the values you assign to them? Is it the case of `container.contents = 99` vs. `container.contents = 98` ? Or is it `container.contents.flag = true` as well? or more so?

Comment: `container.contents` is strictly of type int. I simplified the example for the sake of readability. The actual implementation goes like this: `container.contents = if (Math.random() < 0.4) { 99 } else {0 }` .

Answer (score 0):

You could use a parameter in the constructor:

```
 public class ContainerFiller {
    private amount;

    public ContainerFiller(int amount) {
        this.amount = amount
    }

    public void fill( ContainerClass container ) {
        container.content = this.amount;      
    }
 }
```

And then use it like this:

```
ContinerFiller fillerA = new ContainerFiller(99)
fillerA.fill(someContainer)
```